# write in text file which is embedded in resource files C#

Tags: c#, text, embedded-resource

I can read from embedded text file in resources file when use
MyNamespace.properties.resources.MyTxtFile but it returns the string direct and it is read-only string so I can't change in it.
I want to write in the file

Comment: Do you want a global variable of some sort?  It might be better to create a local copy of the file on the disk, copied from the resource, then use that.  You wouldn't be able to re-embed the file, but you would be able to look for it the next time the app was running.

Comment: but it will not be portable, will it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Resources are embedded and read-only, if you modified them, you would, for example, break the signature.